# How to read the last group of numbers on a line in a .txt file in Java

Tags: java, input, output

I currently have a text file which looks like this:

```
Bob Peach 1000 115
Hugh Mungus 1001 250
Joe Bloggs 1003 555
Joe Walsh 1004 6
Ben Davis 1005 1
```

I need to read the last group of numbers on the line, add them together, and output the answer into a separate text file. How would I go about this?

EDIT: The expected result should be a string inside the output file which looks like this:

```
There are currently 927 points.
```

EDIT 2: Apologies for not explaining it better, but I have now modified what a dummy file would look like using actual names instead of just placeholders. And as you can see it's not always the same amount of characters before the last group of numbers.

EDIT 3: This is what I have tried whilst waiting for responses, and was generally how I thought it should work.

```
public void processFiles()
{        
    total = 0;
    while(input.hasNextInt())
    {
        input.nextInt();
        total = total + input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();
    }

    output.print("There are all together " + 
                 total + " points.");
}
```

The above code however just outputs that there are 0 points.

EDIT 4:

```
public void processFiles()
{        
    total = 0;
    while(input.hasNext())
    {
        String line = input.nextLine();
        String[] splitLine = line.split(" ");
        total += Integer.parseInt(splitLine[splitLine.length - 1]);
    }

    output.print("There are all together " + 
                 total + " points.");
}
```

Comment: you should post your expected result, also what have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm currently at a brick wall, but i've tried using Scanner.nextInt() to direct it to the first group of numbers, but from there I cannot figure out how to make it use the last group.

Comment: Just call Scanner.nextInt() a second time.

Comment: How do you mean, phatfingers? I have now included what my interpretation was.

Comment: @Dacnomaniac brick wall is better than concrete ;-) Have you tried my solution? (By the way, It is along the lines of what Roger proposed...)

Comment: @Plirkee I have read through it, but have not attempted to use it yet as I am still trying to learn what a BufferedReader is as i've never used it before.

Comment: @Plirkee I'm currently trying to compile with Roger's method, and I keep getting the error 'cannot find symbol - variable line'.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming only the information provided (line items are delimited by a single space, and the last item is always the number you want) you can read each line in the file and perform the following on each line.

```
String[] splitLine = line.split(" ");
total += Integer.parseInt(splitLine[splitLine.length - 1]);
```

Reading the file and looping through each line is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: I think i'm missing something, because whenever I try to compile using this, I get an error saying 'cannot find symbol - line'.

Comment: @Dacnomaniac,In this example "line" would be the String that you read in from your file for each line.

Comment: @Dacnomaniac, you can see where line comes from in Plirkee's example.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this ...

You just read file line by line, split each line using `space` character, and convert last part of the line into `integer`.

```
int sum=0;
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
       String[] res = line.split(" ");
       sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(res[res.length - 1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Piklee After sleeping on it, I have tried your solution, but using parts of the scanner class instead, it however does not work as I intended it to and still outputs the sum of the points as 0. Refer to edit to see how it looks now.

Comment: @Dacnomaniac well if you are using scanner ... then it is not exactly my solution, now, is it? Also, what you have posted is a partial code ... from which it is not visible what the `input` variable is ... and we can only guess what is going wrong in your code. I would suggest debugging (use break points), printing out the values of `line` and `splitLine[]` and `total` at each iteration - that way you will find the exact problem ... and will probably fix it without any need for external help...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way if the string has always the same number of lines

```
String LikesDislikes = "Likes: 10
                        Dislikes:10"

String[] lines = LikesDislikes.split("\\n");
            String likes = lines[0];
            String dislikes = lines[1];
```

Comment: Unfortunately it will always be a different number of lines.